# linear independency of irrational vector in $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Show that the following vectors are linearly dependent/independent:
> 1 and $\sqrt{2}$ in vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over field $\mathbb{Q}$

I know that the vectors are linearly independent. But how do I prove it?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$-linear independent and $\mathbb{Q}$-linear independent are quite different. Do you know what a vector space over field $\mathbb{Q}$ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose they were linearly dependent.

Then we have $1\cdot \frac{a}{b} + \sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{c}{d}=0$ for some rational numbers $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$ with $a,b,c,d$ all as integers with $b,d$ nonzero and at least one of $a,c$ nonzero.

Rearranging...

$\sqrt{2}=-\frac{ad}{bc}$

What do you know about $\sqrt{2}$ and what can you conclude then?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational so it is a contradiction, therefore they have to be linearly independent. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p\cdot1+q\sqrt{2}=0$, with $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$. If $q\ne0$, then
$$
\sqrt{2}=-\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}
$$
a contradiction. Therefore $q=0$ and so also $p=0$.

Now try with $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ and you'll see that it's not as easy. The notion of *minimal polynomial* gets handier for the general case.